# Json Schema draft 06 render for android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, jsonschema

Is there any available json form render in xamarin.android and xamarin.ios to render json schema Draft v6 something like [react-jsonschema-form](https://github.com/mozilla-services/react-jsonschema-form#react-jsonschema-form) and [jsonform](https://github.com/joshfire/jsonform)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you want convert a `json` to a layout file in `Xamarin.Android` or `Xamarin.iOS`, as far as I know, there's not.

Comment: Thats sad :-( My requirement was to build a form in android and ios from json schema. Looks like I have to build my own.

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT Is there any native android libraries you know of?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.